# Efficiently group array based on index list

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I'm looking to optimize my code with numpy, but I don't know if it's possible to avoid the python loops etc. in the following code. It groups an array based on the indices in another array:

```
from itertools import repeat

K = 10
# N varies, but is about 2000

objects = [object1, object2, ..., objectN]
indices = [0, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 1, 1, 5, 8, 0, ...]
assert len(objects) == len(indices)

# sorting_arr = [[], [], ..., []]
sorting_arr = [[] for _ in repeat(None, K)]  # [[], [], ..., []] with length K, [[]]*K would make copies
for i, index in enumerate(indices):
    sorting_arr[index].append(objects[i])
```

A small example:

```
K = 3
objects = ["John1", "John2", "John3"]
indices = [0, 2, 0]
```

results in

```
sorting_arr = [["John1", "John3"],[],["John2"]]
```

What is the most efficient way to implement this?

Comment: What is the relationship between objects, indeces and the output? it is unclear to me from the question. You also have the variable name indeces but later check the value of indedes which i think is a typo. Also indices is the proper plural of index btw

Comment: The objects are numpy arrays with shape=(1, 128) and dtype=float32. These vectors are the result of _, des = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None). The indeces list is a list of the index of the closest descriptor of a kmeans algorithm, for every descriptor. I want to sort the descriptors in a separate list per index for further calculations. The indedes was indeed a typo :)

Comment: Did you consider using a `defaultdict` instead of a `list`? It should be a little faster, but also more suited for further use if you have missing indices as per your example

Comment: @DaanSeuntjens I have also added numba version, return format is compromised but also has speed. Might be of some interest

Answer (score 1):

**Using Numba**

Due to numba limitation changed the format to dict
Numba has jit, thus first time will be slow due to compilation but next runs will be fast(in lazy mode).

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import random
import timeit


@nb.njit((nb.int64[:], nb.int64[:], nb.types.DictType(nb.int64, nb.int64[:])))
def sort5(des, indices, d):
    present_indices = np.unique(indices)
    for i in nb.prange(present_indices.shape[0]):
        d[i] = des[indices==present_indices[0]]
    return d


indices = np.array([random.randint(0,9) for i in range(3500)])
des = np.array([i for i in range(len(indices))])
d = nb.typed.Dict.empty(
    key_type=nb.types.int64,
    value_type=nb.types.int64[:],
)

# compiling
print("sort5", timeit.timeit(lambda: sort5(des, indices, d), number=10000))


indices = np.array([random.randint(0,9) for i in range(3500)])
des = np.array([i for i in range(len(indices))])
# reuse compiled version
print("sort5", timeit.timeit(lambda: sort5(des, indices, d), number=10000))


indices = np.array([random.randint(0,9) for i in range(3500)])
des = np.array([i for i in range(len(indices))])
# reuse compiled version
print("sort5", timeit.timeit(lambda: sort5(des, indices, d), number=10000))
```

```
sort5 1.168916742957663
sort5 1.134257352037821
sort5 1.1505634589702822
```

---

I know numpy is needed but a new look like treating the problem using pandas should give speed up for large cases. Also it is possible to use numpy and also numba with pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
objects = ["John1", "John2", "John3"]
indices = [0, 2, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'objects': objects, 'indices': indices})
new_df = df.groupby('indices')['objects'].apply(list).reindex(range(len(indices)))
# indices
# 0    [John1, John3]
# 1               NaN
# 2           [John2]
# Name: objects, dtype: object
l = new_df.to_numpy(na_value=None).tolist()
l[:] = [x if x else [] for x in l]
print(l)
```

```
[['John1', 'John3'], [], ['John2']]
```

Comment: If you wanted to more closely follow the stated output format you could `reindex` by `range(K)` and then `fillna([])` to produce the rows that are currently missing.

Comment: Every day I learn something new about pandas ‍♀️.  I suppose you could make a series with the same index and all empty lists and then `combine_first`.

Answer (score 1):

I've combined all suggestions, and compared their performance.

```
import panda as pd
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy_indexed as npi
from itertools import repeat

def sort1(indices, des):
    sorting = [[] for _ in repeat(None, K)]
    for i, j in enumerate(indices):
        sorting[j].append(des[i])
    return sorting


def sort2(indices, des):
    sorting = [[] for _ in repeat(None, K)]
    for index, d in zip(indices, des):
        sorting[index].append(d)
    return sorting


def sort3(indices, des):
    di = defaultdict(list)
    for i, d in zip(indices, des):
        di[i].append(d)
    return di


def sort4(indices, des):
    arr = np.c_[des, indices]
    arr = arr[np.argsort(arr[:, -1])]
    return np.split(arr[:, :-1], np.unique(arr[:, -1], return_index=True)[1][1:])


def sort5(indices, des):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'objects': des, 'indices': indices})
    return df.groupby('indices')['objects'].apply(list).reindex(range(len(indices)))


def sort6(indices, des):
    return npi.group_by(indices, des)[1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    indices = [1,5,2,0,8,0,0,4,1,2,4,9,1,...]
    des = [i for i in range(len(indices))] # len(indices) = 3249
    
    print("sort1", timeit.timeit(lambda: sort1(indices, des), number=10000))
    print("sort2", timeit.timeit(lambda: sort2(indices, des), number=10000))
    print("sort3", timeit.timeit(lambda: sort3(indices, des), number=10000))
    print("sort4", timeit.timeit(lambda: sort4(indices, des), number=10000))
    print("sort5", timeit.timeit(lambda: sort5(indices, des), number=10000))
    print("sort6", timeit.timeit(lambda: sort6(indices, des), number=10000))
```

results:

```
sort1 7.003451800000001
sort2 6.221672100000001
sort3 6.611176099999998
sort4 5.9127765
sort5 24.296690499999997
sort6 2.7992552999999987
```

`sort1->4` change positions depending on the run, `sort5` is the slowest but the clear winner is `sort6`, the numpy-indexed method. (install: `pip install numpy_indexed`).

Comment: Thanks for summary. How big K did you use while testing? Using same K I want to try numba if possible

Comment: My K was 10, All input is appreciated!

Comment: Also what was N? For N=2000 2seconds is kind of very slow also

Comment: N is variable, typical numbers for N are between 2000-3500. In the example above it was 3249.

Comment: @eroot163pi the 2.799 seconds is for doing it 10_000 times, so per iteration it is about 0.2799ms.

Answer (score 0):

The will depend on how you're constructing your' objects' and 'indices' lists. In principle you could just build a list of tuples where each tuple is (index, object) then use the builtin sorted() function which will do exactly what you need. Here's a contrived example:-

```
L = [(1, 'A'), (3, 'C'), (2, 'B'), (13, 'M')]
print(sorted(L))
```

...which will emit:-

[(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (13, 'M')]

Comment: Not totally what I'm looking for, I'm starting with two separate lists and rearranging into tuples would be costly as well. Also, there could be multiple indices that are the same, which should combine into a single list.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
for index, obj in zip(indices, objects):
    sorting_arr[index].append(obj)
```

is slightly more performant

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the empty lists (such as for the value 1 in your second example) this can be accomplished as follows:

```
arr = np.c_[objects,indices]
print(arr)
arr = arr[np.argsort(arr[:,1])]
sorting_arr = np.split(arr[:,0], np.unique(arr[:, 1], return_index=True)[1][1:])
```

This works by creating an array of the objects and indices, sorting by the indices and then splitting based on unique values of the indices. This might be slow because it requires a sort but it avoids the for loop and the creation of a large list of empty lists. If you do require empty lists in place of indices that are missing this will not work.

```
bins = np.unique(arr[:,1])
```

would give you the corresponding indices to loop through if needed ([0,2] in your example)